# PHP Web Scraping from table HTML tags

Tags: php, web-scraping

I would like to scrap data from this site  https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/southwest-airlines-wn-swa

The code Written by Mr Adam on this page brings back all the content however
i would like to return only 9 records in sets of three, filtered from charlot,washington and columbus respectively

```
    Flight  From            To      Aircraft    Registration
============================================================================    
WN8     Charlotte  (CLT)    Houston (HOU)   B737        N7716A      Live     
WN9     Charlotte  (CLT)    Houston (HOU)   B733        N7716A      Live    
WN10    Charlotte  (CLT)    Houston (HOU)   B737        N7716A      Live    
WN21    Washington (DCA)    Orlando (MCO)   B743        N568WN      Live     
WN22    Washington (DCA)    Orlando (MCO)   B755        N568WN      Live      
WN23    Washington (DCA)    Orlando (MCO)   B776        N568WN      Live
WN119   Columbus   (CMH)    Fort Myers      B712        N964WN      Live    
WN120   Columbus   (CMH)    Fort Myers      B732        N964WN      Live    
WN121   Columbus   (CMH)    Fort Myers      B764        N964WN      Live
```

Now Mr Adam's code looks like this below, it brings all the data from that site, but what i need is some small alter in the code below to just give me a small filtered sample as indicated above.

```
  <?php
$url = "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/southwest-airlines-wn-swa";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
if($doc->loadHTML($html))
{
    $result = new \DOMDocument();
    $result->formatOutput = true;
    $table = $result->appendChild($result->createElement("table"));
    $thead = $table->appendChild($result->createElement("thead"));
    $tbody = $table->appendChild($result->createElement("tbody"));

    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

    $newRow = $thead->appendChild($result->createElement("tr"));

    foreach($xpath->query("//table[@id='tablepress-2']/thead/tr/th[position()>0]") as $header)
    {
        $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("th", trim($header->nodeValue)));
    }

    foreach($xpath->query("//table[@id='tablepress-2']/tbody/tr") as $row)
    {
        $newRow = $tbody->appendChild($result->createElement("tr"));

        foreach($xpath->query("./td[position()>0 and position()<6]", $row) as $cell)

        {
            $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("td", trim($cell->nodeValue)));
        }
    }

    echo $result->saveXML($result->documentElement);
}
?>
```

I created an Array with [huston,charlotte,washington] states i would use to filter and compare in the loop, so i embeded it into the main loop but it
does not seem to work ,i mean i dont know if am doing the right thing here.

```
$states = array("huston,charlotte,washington");

foreach($xpath->query("./td[position()>0 and position()<6]", $row) as $cell)

        {        
             for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) 
                 {

                 if($xpath->query("./td[position()=2", $row)==$x)
            {
                   $newRow->appendChild($result->createElement("td",   trim($cell->nodeValue)));
            }
                } 


        }
```

I will be greatful for any help rendered thank you

Comment: This site is not designed for get free workers for your projects. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Thats fair, okay i am looking at this area in the loop

Comment: What did you do in  the end @Bels ?

Comment: am still new in this field and still trying to work it out following the original plan but no success yet, the loops am implementing are giving me wrong results so i guess i will just keep trying

Answer (score 0):

**Better Option**

Web scraping isn't ideal, it's slow, messy, and as soon as this site is updated, your code will break. A better alternative would be to use an API to fetch this data, e.g. http://uk.flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/ It's got clear documentation, and you can pretty much copy and paste their code snippets to get the data you need. (there's a couple of other sites with similar API's too, so have a look on Google).

**In Answer to your Question**

If you really want to use PHP to web scrape HTML tables then something like this should work (adapted from one of [Steve Lacey's](https://github.com/stevelacey) repos):

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();

// It's rare you'll have valid XHTML, suppress any errors- it'll do its best.
@$doc->loadhtml($string);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Modify the XPath query to match the content
foreach($xpath->query('//table')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $rows) {
  $cells = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');

  // Do stuff with the data
  echo $cells->item(0)->textContent;
  echo $cells->item(1)->textContent;
  echo $cells->item(2)->textContent;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) on SO will also help. It explains in quite some detail the best methods for extracting info from HTML tables, using PHP